# Proof explanation for a function bounded by $M\,|z|^m$ being a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

The problem in question is:

> Let $f$ be entire and $M\in\mathbb{R}$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t $|f(z)|\leq M|z|^m$.
> Show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree less than $m$.

I'm studying a proof and can't quite figure out one thing. The proof goes as follows:

> $n \geq m+2$:
> \begin{align}
>   |f(0)^{(n)}|&=\left|\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz \right|\\
> &\leq\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint \left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz \right|\\
> &\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint \left|\frac{M|z|^m}{z^{n+1}}dz \right|\\
> &\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi i}M2\pi R\frac{1}{R^{n+1-m}}\rightarrow 0, R\rightarrow0
> \end{align}
> $|f(0)^{(n)}|=0, \forall n \geq m+2$, hence $f$ is a polynomial.

Where the path we're integrating over is a ball of radius $R$ and centered at $0$. The only part I'm not quite getting is the $n\geq m+2$. Why is this required? It seems to me that $n$ need only be greater than m, or greater or equal to $m+1$ for the last part to converge to zero

Comment: That is correct. The calculation gives  $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for $n \ge m+1$.

Comment: Oh I see, then  it was a mistake. Thanks!